# How to use "The technical name of the Widget, used for css class and alternatives

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to figure out how to use the "technical name of the Widget, used for css class and alternatives". My assumption is that when I add #custom section in my sites.css file it will be referenced to "custom" specified in the "technical name of the Widget, used for css class and alternatives." field.

Thanks
Johan

Answer (score 0):

No, `#custom` would mean that's the id. Look at the element surrounding the widget. You'll see that it's added as a class, not an id.